# QT Modeless dialog window dos'nt response to the move command

Tags: c++, qt

im using  Modeless dialog in my application , and when i try to  use the Modeless dialog  move command from the MainWindow
the Modeless dialog didint even show up,why ? (by the way if i remove the move command every   thing works and i can see the dialog when called, i try to move it to the systray era.
here somecode:
M

```
odelessDialog* ModelessDialog= new ModelessDialog(this);
ModelessDialog->setModal(false);
ModelessDialog->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
int topLeft_x = m_SystrayReq.topLeft().x();
int topLeft_y = m_SystrayReq.topLeft().y();
// the valus of x & y are just fine .
        ModelessDialog->move(topLeft_x,topLeft_y);
        ModelessDialog->show();
```

Comment: As the dialog has a parent, move() is relative to the parent widget.
Your systray coordinates are probably global? Then use QWidget::mapFromGlobal() to map them.

Answer (score 3):

As the dialog has a parent, the coordinates move() takes are relative to the parent widget. Your systray coordinates are probably global? Then use QWidget::mapFromGlobal() to map them.

Comment: This is likely the case, which means that if his parent dialog is anywhere but in the extreme top-left corner, he's probably moved his dialog off-screen, which would account for not being able to see it at all.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are moving the dialog to be at the top-left corner of the system tray.  The move command places the top-left corner of the dialog where you tell it to move.  If [Frank's global-local changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853154/qt-modeless-dialog-window-dosnt-response-to-the-move-command/2855000#2855000) don't make a difference, it might be that the systray will always draw above your dialog (thus not allowing it to be shown).